# After execution of python file in ubuntu machine using crontab csv file is not beeing returned

Tags: python, csv, cron

Hi I am trying to schedule job using crontab in ubuntu machine I have written python codes to extract .csv file from the given data.

The codes are working fine and returning `.csv` file when I type in the command `python3 app.py` in the Terminal(CMD) of Ubuntu machine.

But when i schedule a Job using crontab the file is being executed but it is not returning the expected `.csv` file.

The crontab is working fine when i type in `45 14 * * * bash./home/test1.sh>myfile.sh` it is returning myfile.sh(which is a shell script file)

When i try to run `python3 app.py` the codes are being executed but it is not returning the expected `.csv` file. The command I used is

```
55 15 * * *  python3 ./Documents/user/app.py
```

I want this code to return `.csv` file but it is not returning any file. where did I go wrong

kindly help on this regard.

Comment: Do you have access to logs files ? It may be a repertory permission problem while creating the file.

Comment: I will try this and let you know @Camille